# how to move to hooks props type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
--- useParams.ts---
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const useParamsData = (initData) => {
  const [params, setChangeParams] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    setChangeParams(initData);
  }, []);
  return {
    params,
    setChangeParams,
  };
};
```

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParamsData } from './useParamsData';
import './style.css';

export const ComponentA = () => {
  const initData = {
    age: 0,
    name: 'jhon',
    county: '',
  };
  const { params, setChangeParams } = useParamsData(initData);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParamsData } from './useParamsData';
import './style.css';

export const ComponentB = () => {
    const initData = {
    category: 'All',
    status: 'All',
    type: 'All',
    module: 'All',
    keword: '',
    startDate: '',
    endDate: '',
  };
  const { params, setChangeParams } = useParamsData(initData);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

When delivering props to useParamshooks with different key and value values of initData to each component, can you deliver the type to the props and designate it as the params type of useParams?

UseParams can specify the initData type of each component, but this will cause the hassle of having to specify the type every time the component increases.
I'd like an automated method instead of the one below

```
--- useParams.ts---

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

type A = {
  age: string
    name:  string
    county: string,
}
type B = {
  category: string
    status: string
    type: string
    module: string
    keword : string
    startDate: string
}

export const useParamsData = (initData : A | B) => {
  const [params, setChangeParams] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    setChangeParams(initData);
  }, []);
  return {
    params,
    setChangeParams,
  };
};
```

First of all, thank you so much for your kind reply.

Actually, the original code is as follows

UseParams hooks are hooks that try to put each data in the prams when an event occurs. This is to prevent duplicate use in other places such as change/onclick.

However, in useState, init data can be designated as generic
It's hard to get it at jotai atom, so I'm thinking about it

[See Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LTAEAcEMCdIWwM4GUAukUFMB0KEmAFACWc4A9tCqAN7plwC+oAZtPaAOQBWZaRHBDAA9ylUCgCe4DKAAKMeABUpMgLygAIugwAxIgBtM0ZdNAAfUAhTQiAOwDm50ACUMkAMYosAYQAWkBwwAUQA3DFsUAB4ACUUAWQAZAElbcABXFCD9DDhwlAA+JwBFW0gAQQATCvlYRBMZCxLylDQUd196gG0AXScNDD59AHE0ogqMSor6wREKKklTJAGa+AR60HVqAlBQCvRIAC45BThpnYBrDAkAfiOrGwcCBgIZ0Sp3MlsrCBOEMpR2Oo6HAABTUBgAShewjeoA+XyoCGWv3+gNAwJBtjS+n0ABpQCD7AN8UiUPjqLt9vjLhJQAwjksUCs6ioIRtClsdvDvuBoBgQhtQESUCCoLU-gC4FDtqAAPQAKiFA1AoTyx3FoHlsplRGYBJpoAAZIbxCoyHq9mgNqp1BwyAAjLgYTwcI0mjhoaDC112SloNmcnaWAailGS8kyoOgLAx3n83GRoOdGndI6WyA4GDCrAhSD6NIYBNRyGJvkoNLQWwy54yhVKqgAaSuoFz+ZkzIQmu1O11+quAcTpND4tRcAjUZ2MawcZCRYnyauqb9kDnOxLUbLFara6eUPwIBeJFhrg8ZJooDSSKCzGYzrPl4wqG0dJYbDgnD5p44AG4Xq85iwaS2J4RCfBeSIdloaCRIo+QgnYRAoFBhygIoA5cp83ydGKqwksi4q9OoD6jjBThYjicE4Ygo7StyiIDH4AREh2gogvyeRHDsJ6eD4-iBKqEQxPECRLNknhZDkeSFE43FeIx-FhIJsSJCk6SZNkuQRPkbKqByiayrKwYoKJd4JEQVhgsuRzsREdJQlGpIdpZ6bWYpXietmrYFtSVyuXkmZegMWClLkdnVpGMqbpWNCJlRCCrkZ8nMb8c4ML+aXQrMYh0aA3j0OQth5GUrE6XpGEIqACFIfsgqBjskBEkcAAMCUhRgRzcL4nwcAlHxAZIHU9dWv7ld8FJxXhKBJRgLFMEREG-Mh8G2IhyEQiNoBRbYBKJpEFRECE+SJkGkRImJVBtaoABE7jaPYFASFdoCfNNqjUKS00dgwspHROoCRHYamgJdN13Q9T0vXxRJvR9UMzb832-Sdsr7YdMrrU8v7-tlmFUHlpCfHkABCJXsjFUY5VVyG1Ymt2YPd0ASB1ZQ4kNDmtJezOswlCztZwLP6GzQZwGQFTYnzHAC0LFwYAA7hQFSDQlVgwNVmBK4m4QVFBEtCxlo1UONKWJXDs2Cg+kH7Mtq37BjOxbTtUZ7QdSNO2dd7A-AGDXXTGAM49z22K970MabCM-cd-2Axknu5D7YOMxDQdwzDodMfD4qI7tKMu+j6W-kAA)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `useParamsData` to be a [generic function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

You just declare a generic type parameter, say `T`, and set it to the type of `initData`.

```
export function useParamsData<T>(initData: T) {
  const [params, setChangeParams] = useState<T>({}); // type error here

  useEffect(() => {
    setChangeParams(initData);
  }, []);
  return {
    params,
    setChangeParams,
  };
};
```

The return type of that function is:

```
{
    params: T;
    setChangeParams: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>>;
}
```

So whatever you provide as `T` will will propagate through.

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=5.2.2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgKIBmZSG2RSAyjCjEnAL5xlQQhwDkUqDLwDcAKHFIAHpFgd8AOwzAI8gsQAKKKChCEAIkxQAeACoA+ABTB5wGAcYAuOCYCUuUXDhoVheAG0wLR1CbGIYAGEACxR5AHMkTW1dAF04AF41ekZmU0scVhdhOAB6YrgAd2AAGyq4ACMWFDgYAE8wFiQoLig4SM6kcU9ackoMCws3NLN3T08wqJj4xOCrGztDQo82bD9kzc8BGHwoVRwtz0CkkPO4eei4hKDdTC3WMTeJaWh4b3lfOHC3Eg8iQ8hgAEF0nAJulpmdPL9-tZbPYmhl4bMUPEnAAGF6zODyHRIJy8ABWkRUvHxs28ClapOprzECJ88Dwl2CoSQEXuSyehDYUNoy10qNWKI2LLgh2OqgsNyMABNgAA3Mw3TxGMBmBhaeBIFUwayxZoQW5IFiEbgsEBY4BoXooMDteQAOiMxR1iuKKvVW02H1EUhkPzZAKBKlBMAAQlCYVMZrTw8j1owoRiEUwkLFoC1SeCakyCb4mEQC0WaZ5Wu0K1Vi7MQBAlfgqiS+IX61W4ABrJDlaBKxnd0uwezt3gNzygpXj4fMraI9lwTnPC28xaPK5CjIigXi1Oo-Yynly6GKv0aglanV62SG2wms0Wq02uB22IOp0u0Eer1X2ZPUvAN3jEIA)

---

However, as noted above you have a type error still on this line:

```
const [params, setChangeParams] = useState<T>({});
```

Which is:

```
Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T | (() => T)'.(2345)
```

The problem is that an empty object is probably not a valid value for whatever `T` is. So to make this structure work, you'd need to allow a default value.  Perhaps `null` would make sense?

```
const [params, setChangeParams] = useState<T | null>(null);
```

The way to solve that is up to you and what logic you want.

---

But I will say, are you sure you need that `useEffect`?

This will do the same thing:

```
export function useParamsData<T>(initData: T) {
  const [params, setChangeParams] = useState(initData);
  return {
    params,
    setChangeParams,
  };
};
```

The only difference is that the state *starts* as the value from `initData` so you never have to default value that comes before your `initData`.

And that point, why do you have this hook at all when all it does is return the result of `useState`?

Comment: You have added an article below the text
Please, give me a break.